# Matrix,Linear algebra,polynomial,finite field,notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

In the book by Arora and Barak,Computational Complexity,on page 168,1st paragraph, there is a notation which I do not understand. They write
For every $n \times n$ matrix $A$,and $i\in [n]$,we define $D_A(i)$ to be the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix $A_{1,i}$, i.e. A with first row and $i$th column deleted.If $x\in F\setminus[n]$;then we define $D_A(x)$ in the unique way such that for every $j,k\in [n-1]$,the function $(D_A(x))_{j,k}$ is a univariate polynomial of degree at most $n$.

> My question is how this univariate polynomial is created,
>       and how uniqueness determines its form.Is this a polynomial in $x$?
>       What is $D_A(x)$?

Comment: There is a problem wth the question in that $D_A(i)$ is defined (only) when $i\in[n]$, but then $D_A(x)$ is used where $x\in[n]$ is explicitly _excluded_! It is not so clear what $F$ is where $x$ lives; maybe the finite field (whose elements I would have a hard time matching up with column indices $i$), but in any case if some $x\in F$ would happen to also be a column index $i\in[n]$, then that value is forbidden.

Comment: The phrase "defined in the unique wys such that" is plain nonsense. I can define $(D_A(x))_{j,k}$ to be always $0$ if I feel so inclined. Or I could define it to be $(X+j)(X+k)$. Or whatever. These are both (all) polynomials of degree at most $n$ (assuming $n\geq2$) so there is no uniqueness.

Comment: [SEE THIS REFRENCE](https://books.google.cz/books?id=8Wjqvsoo48MC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=%22univariate+polynomial+of+degree+at+most%22+barak+arora&source=bl&ots=znIU6mWnJE&sig=VqMkn-hHhf3z8cAKv8B8QdcVqmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI4OO_69XuxgIVpe9yCh2xMAv3#v=onepage&q=%22univariate%20polynomial%20of%20degree%20at%20most%22%20barak%20arora&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it. First $D_A(i)$ is defined (as a matrix) for $n$ particular values in your field $K=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Then for every matrix position, there is a unique univariate polynomial $P\in K[x]$ of degree *strictly less than* $n$ (your book is off by one here) such that the corresponding entry of $D_A(i)$ equals the evaluation $P[x:=i]$ (this is a standard polynomial interpoliation result). Then define $D_A\in M_{n-1}(K[x])$ (a matrix with polynomial entries) to have these (interpolation) polynomials as entries (in their respective matrix positions).

Your book is very sloppy in using the *same* notation $A_{i,j}$ to denote in the first sentence a matrix obtained by dropping row$~i$ and column$~j$ from $A$, and then in the last sentence (with $D_A(x)$ as matrix) to denote simply the $i,j$ entry of the matrix.

Comment: Ok.And why is $x$ chosen from $F\setminus [n]$?

Comment: Because for $x\in[n]$ those matrix entries were already defined; the purpose here (though very badly expressed) is to define those entries for _other_ values $x$ by polynomial interpolation.